# POST and GET request, using them in PHP

Tags: java, php, ajax, post, get

I am making a new application and am using php for the server end of things (to record the data). I am aware there is POST and GET requests. However I wasn't aware that it matters which one you use, I only realised this when I accidently stumbled upon a page and read it. At the moment I am using GET and I think I should be using POST. Can anyone tell me which type I should use for sending data to a server? Like numbers and strings that should be private?

If I should be using POST can anyone show me an example in php? I have a player_count.php file which when the server receives it it comes in like this http://typt.co.uk/api/send/player_count.php?username=USERNAME&secret_key=SECRET_KEY&player_count=5(example) How would the client send this when it turns into a POST request? And how would I read the data sent? Would I just change $_GET['username'] to $_POST['username'] ? I am not sure.

Here is my current player_count.php file:

```
<?php

function get_client_ip() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
       $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    return $ipaddress;
}

include_once "connect_db.php";

$loc = ""; //set equal to just two "" to make it this directory!

$list=$_GET['list'];
$secret_key=$_GET['secret_key'];
$username=$_GET['username'];
$server_no=$_GET['servernum'];

$ip = get_client_ip();

$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
if(mysql_num_rows($rs) == 0){
    echo("#-2");
    return;
}
$a_skey = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $users_plan = $row['account_permission'];
    $a_skey = $row['secret_key'];
}
if($a_skey == null) $a_skey = '';

if(!($secret_key == $a_skey)){
    echo("#-1");
    return;
}

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM banned WHERE username='$username'");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) >= 1){
    echo("#2");
    return;
}

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM locked WHERE username='$username'");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) >= 1){
    echo("#3");
    return;
}

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ipban WHERE IP='$ip'");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) >= 1){
    echo("#4");
    return;
}

if($users_plan == 'free' && $server_no >= 2){
    echo("#1");
    return;
}else if($users_plan == 'personal' && $server_no >= 2){
    echo("#1");
    return;
}else if($users_plan == 'basic' && $server_no >= 2){
    echo("#1");
    return;
}else if($users_plan == 'premium' && $server_no >= 2){
    echo("#1");
    return;
}else if($users_plan == 'network1' && $server_no >= 6){
    echo("#1");
    return;
}else if($users_plan == 'network2' && $server_no >= 11){
    echo("#1");
    return;
}
$file = fopen("$loc$secret_key/player_list.txt","w");
fwrite($file,$list);
fclose($file);
echo "#0";
return;

?>
```

P.S If anyone knows Java aswell how would I send a POST request from java?

Answer (score 0):

First off - if you use `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_GET` it will work with **both** **GET** and **POST** methods.

For sending **POST** methods from Java it would be helpful if you'd give more details on your project scope.

[HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) has same good examples for you to start off with.

[This Blog](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/) contains some basic Java code (no libs needed)

Comment: ok hey Jan, well my project allows minecraft servers to POST data to a web-server and this web-server records it. The reason why I need to know how to do this in Java is because the minecraft servers are made in java. But can I just leave it as it is? Since i think I heard that GET requests have a limit on length for args, and the args could get pretty long... So I think I NEED a POST request, dont I? I will use `$_POST` then, does it work as I said?

Comment: In your PHP I'd do $_REQUEST as I said - that way you can slowly move from simple GET to slightly more comple POST without the need to change PHP code again

Comment: Thankyou - I think I found my answer :)

Comment: you might want to accept it (if my answer helped) or add an answer to your own question and accept that, so others can learn from this question.